# Mysql and eclipse setup

Tags: mysql, eclipse, connection

I am unable to see **mysql** in *connection profile* in eclipse, I have tried of creating a new connection but all in vain.

Also how can I solve class not found error.

Comment: Post your code. The 'class not found' means you are referring to a class which declaration can not be found (usually one forgets to add proper imports).

Comment: is project build path properly configured?

Comment: ClassNotFoundException usually occurs when you do not have the correct imports or a required jar is not on the classpath. Or a class has attempted to be accessed via reflection and the class has not been loaded, or available on the classpath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Install Eclipse on your computer
2. Download JDBC (Java DataBase Connectivity) from http://www.mysql.com/products/conector.  Select "Platform Independent"
3. Unzip/unpack it. Open the new folder create
   by the unpacking. Make sure you see a jar file in the folder, with a
   name similar to mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar
4. Create a new java project in Eclipse. Call it MySQLTest1 (or whatever name you    want).
5. Drag & drop the JDBC connector jar file
   (mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar) to your project in Eclipse.
   Select copy file and not "link file".
6. Create 2 java classes in the
   project (source code given below)

   ```
       Main.java, and 
       MySQLAccess.java
   ```
7. Click on mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar in the project to
   highlight it
8. Control-click or right-click on it to open the pop-up:
   pick Build-Path, and then Configure Build-Path
9. A new window opens
   up. In the right hand-side, click on the Libraries tab.
10. Click on Add
    JARs
11. In the JAR Selection window, double-click on MySQLTest1 (or
    whatever your project name is).
12. Select the
    mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar library.
13. Click Ok.
14. The mysql
    connector is now a library available when compiling your java code.