# Why is my mysql connector jar file not accessbile from eclipse although I have build path to mysql connector jar file?

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc, mysql-connector

I have downloaded MySQL connector jar file because I have to connect a java program with a database. After downloading the jar file, I built the path to MySQL connector jar file in eclipse (Since I am using eclipse ide for java developers 2019-12). The jar file is getting added but when I write the program and try to import the java.sql.* package, it gives me an error stating that the package is not accessible. Please help me. I am working on my college assignment.

Comment: If you have a `module-info.java` file in your default package, delete it or learn about [JPMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System).

Comment: Add `requires java.sql;` to the `module-info.java`.

Comment: Look over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37477140/2976876